# Which one should I use to create splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, cross-platform, splash-screen

as you know, some apps have splash screen. I have learned the make splash screen with native codes on Flutter.

For example:
android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" />

   <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/hwalogo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

So,I will have splash screen without dart. Also, iOS side has too. Before the that, I was creating splash screen like homepage or login. My question is which one should I use to be more suitable? Many Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe both of them, you can use native splash screen utils to get rid of the white screen when you open the app.

At the same time, you can use a splash screen that you create with dart and make some api calls, async jobs etc.

Or you can use a prebuilt splash screens like [splashscreen](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen) or [easy_splash_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_splash_screen).

So it is about your needs, do the one that suits your case.

Comment: clearly, I got it, the usage depends of my needs. Thanks a lot friend.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a splash screen using Dart code itself. Sharing the code for reference :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants/constants.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  bool? loginCheck;  //checking the shared preference and navigating accordingly
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loginCheck = prefs!.getBool('login');
    navigate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Material(
      child: Center(child: Text('Loading....')),
    );
  }

  navigate() async {
    if (loginCheck == true) {
      Future(() => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home'));
    } else {
      Future(() => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login'));
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, you can provide a delay of some seconds manually but the above code actually does the job.

Comment: totally agree with you, but I know that usage and I'm already creating splash screen like that. But if I use with native codes, will it be more performance?

Comment: For that, you'll have to write native code for both android and ios. And yes, that is gonna be more performant.

Comment: I got it, it would be more performance. Many Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

A native splash screen has a few advantages:

- It is shown immediately with no delay.
- No blank white screen is shown before your app loads.

The package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) can generate the native splash screen and it also now has the ability for the splash screen to remain onscreen while you load app resources.  Full disclosure: I maintain this package.